# Multiple textboxes input and multiple textboxes output via array

Tags: c#, arrays, textbox

For an assignment I have to programm a form which compaires the avarage temperature with the given temperature (in which the user can fill in). The input is in 7 different textboxes, and the output has to be in 7 different textboxes as well. I got the input of the different textboxes into an array.

However, I have trouble in calculation the differences between temperatures. Also I have trouble with the output textboxes, I can not get a loop to work for placing the values into the 7 different output textboxes. I have to do the calculation via an array..

Maybe someone can see where I went wrong?

```
private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string temperature = Convert.ToDouble(txtZo.Text + txtMa.Text + txtDi.Text +
                    txtWo.Text + txtDo.Text + txtVr.Text + txtZa.Text).ToString("0.00");
    double average =  10,2 ;
    double resultaatZo = 1;   // I think there could be a loop for this right?
    double resultaatMa = 1;
    double resultaatDi = 1;
    double resultaatWo = 1;
    double resultaatDo = 1;
    double resultaatVr = 1;
    double resultaatZa = 1;
    int regelnummer = 1;
for (int i = 1; i < temperature.Length; i++)
{
    resultaatZo = average - temperature[0];
    txtAfwZo.Text = txtAfwZo.Text + resultaatZo.ToString();

    resultaatMa = average - temperature[1];
    txtAfwMa.Text = txtAfwMa.Text + resultaatMa.ToString();

    resultaatDi = average - temperature[2];
    txtAfwDi.Text = txtAfwDi.Text + resultaatDi.ToString();

    resultaatWo = average - temperature[3];
    txtAfwWo.Text = txtAfwWo.Text + resultaatWo.ToString();
        
    resultaatDo = average - temperature[4];
    txtAfwDo.Text = txtAfwDo.Text + resultaatDo.ToString();

    resultaatVr = average - temperature[5];
    txtAfwVr.Text = txtAfwVr.Text + resultaatVr.ToString();

    resultaatZa = average - temperature[6];
    txtAfwZa.Text = txtAfwZa.Text + resultaatZa.ToString();
}
```

Design of my programm.

[image]

I already spent hours and hours on this and I am really lost.

Thank you!

Comment: Please be more specific as to what you "have trouble" with.

Comment: You can make a list to make it easer to enumerate : List<TextBox> boxes = new List<TextBox>() { txtAfwZo, txtAfwMa,txtAfwDi,txtAfwWo,txtAfwDo, txtAfwVr,txtAfwZa};

Comment: You have `string temperature`, but then are accessing `temperature` like you expect it to have an array of values with `temperature[0]`.  As written, that is simply accessing the first character in the string.  You need to make an ARRAY of double values and assign each individual textbox entry to the appropriate spot in the array.  Afterwards, you can then iterate over the array to compute a sum and subsequently an average.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this way:
Private fields in Form class ....

```
    private Label[] _answers = new Label[NUMBER_OF_VERIABLES];

    private TextBox[] _textBoxes = new TextBox[NUMBER_OF_VERIABLES];

    private double[] _results = new double[NUMBER_OF_VERIABLES];
```

In click button event handler:

```
 void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_VERIABLES; i++)
    {
        this._answers[i].Text =  double.TryParse(this._textBoxes[i].Text, out this._results[i]) ? $"{averageTemp + this._results[i]}" : INFORMATION_EMPTY_VALUE;
    }
}
```